# Make condition for weight equal to a specific value in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

The code below works fine. Basically, a clustered map is generated. To know the cluster number, I use the `TOPSIS` multicriteria method. For the `TOPSIS` method, it is necessary to choose criteria weights, which usually range from 0 to 1. Since I have two criteria, I created two `numericInput` to generate the weights. If you test the APP you will see that it works, the only case that doesn't work is if you put `weights1` equal to 1. Therefore, I would like to put some condition or something, that when this happens, consider, weight 1 = 0.9 and not equal to 1.

```
library(shiny)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(topsis)

function.cl<-function(df,k,weights){
  
  #database df
  df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.4,-23.5), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.3, -49.4, -49.8, -49.6,-49.4,-49.2), 
                     Coverage = c (1526, 2350, 3526, 2469, 1285, 2433, 2456),
                     Production = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

  #Topsis
  df1 <- df[c(4:5)]
  df1<-data.matrix(df1)
  i <- c("-", "+") 
  #weights <- c(0.3,0.7) 
  scaled2<-topsis(df1, weights, i)
  scaled2$rank <- rank(-scaled2$score,ties.method= "first")
  colnames(scaled2)<-c("Alternatives","score","Ranking")
  
  k<-subset(scaled2, Ranking==2)$Alternatives #cluster number
  
  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 
  df1<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  
  
  #Color and Icon for map
  ai_colors <-c("red","gray","blue","orange","green","beige")
  
  clust_colors <- ai_colors[df$cluster]
  icons <- awesomeIcons(
    icon = 'ios-close',
    iconColor = 'black',
    library = 'ion',
    markerColor =  clust_colors)
  
  # Map for all clusters:
  m1<-leaflet(df1) %>% addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude) %>%
    addAwesomeMarkers(lat=~df$Latitude, lng = ~df$Longitude, icon=icons, label=~as.character(df$cluster)) %>% 
    addLegend( position = "topright", title="Cluster", colors = ai_colors[1:max(df$cluster)],labels = unique(df$cluster))
  
  plot1<-m1
  
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          numericInput("weights1", label = h5("Choose the weight 1"),min = 0, max = 1, value = NA, step = 0.1),
                          numericInput("weights2", label = h5("Choose the weight 2"),min = 0, max = 1, value = NA, step = 0.1)
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", (leafletOutput("Leaf1",width = "95%", height = "600")))))
                        
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,k,weights=c(input$weights1, input$weights2))
  })
  
  output$Leaf1 <- renderLeaflet({
    req(weights=c(input$weights1, input$weights2))
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$weights1, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "weights2")
    updateNumericInput(session, 'weights2',
                       value = 1 - input$weights1)
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the question. why not just limit your input `weight1` to have max of 0.99 or 0.9?. or just add a statement within the function that changes weights[1] to 0.99 or 0.9 if it equals 1?

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's just that I'm using other multicriteria methods at the same time. And other methods let you put weight 1 equal to 1, only `TOPSIS` doesn't. That's why I didn't change `max ` in `numericInput`. Now with the most complete information, do you have any solution to solve it?

Comment: my second suggestion seems to fit. when you are using`weights` in TOPSIS, can you not simply do `weights[1]=ifelse(weights[1]==1,.99,weights[1])`

Comment: Good approach, but it didn't work when I tested it. If you can test in the code above, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `topsis` function requires positive weights; if `weight1` is 1, then `weight2` is non-positive (it's zero). So, before you pass the `weights` vector to topsis make sure that both of these is non-zero. You can handle this in lots of ways, here is one example, where I add the following lines before the call to `topis()`:

```
if(0 %in% weights) {
  weights[which(weights==0)] <- 0.01
  weights[which(weights==1)] <- 0.99
}
scaled2<-topsis(df1, weights, i)
```

Comment: Perfect, that's it! Thanks for the help @langtang. Please, can you see a question that I've been trying to solve for a long time, but I still can't? Maybe you can help me, if you need additional information, you can contact me. It's this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71506509/how-to-link-selected-cluster-in-shiny-app

Comment: I tried to provide an answer for that one too. Please let me know if I need to adjust it in anyway.

Comment: langtang, taking advantage of this question that I used TOPSIS and you solved it, I asked this question here that also uses TOPSIS: https:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71528241/adjust-selecinput-so-that-it-works-for-two -different-methods-at-the-same-time.
Could this resolution approach you've taken be used on this other issue?